# Double /Single quote syntax

Tags: linux

When querying a list and putting the value in a variable and trying to use the variable in another script it doenst get the format needed.

- script 1:
  cilist=$(opr-ci-list.sh -view_name TN_UD_REFRESH_MRE | sed -e '/^[TL-]/d' -e '/^\s*$/d' -e 's/^....//' | awk -vORS=, '{ print $1 }' | sed 's/,$/\n/')

The output of this script will be ID's comma seperated string like: 7c553435c1376c8f5f020fcee0b8ef51,7d427dd75235bf513286d3210e1bd787

echo $cilist
7c553435c1376c8f5f020fcee0b8ef51,7d427dd75235bf513286d3210e1bd787

=> no quotes to be seen when doing a echo

- script 2:
  opr-downtime.sh -cis "\"$cilist\""

i receive an error because the are single quotes surrounding the variable:

-cis '"7c553435c1376c8f5f020fcee0b8ef51,7d427dd75235bf513286d3210e1bd787 "'

I tried several syntax ways but keep getting the wrong input for the second script. Or i have no quotes or quotes like `'"` in front and behind.

Any help or feedback on the correct syntax would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you using that input in the second script. That's probably where the problems are at.

Comment: script.sh -cis "$cilist"

Comment: @jhx i adjusted my post but cannot make it any clearer to illustrate the problem. In my second script the variable produced by script 1 gets surrounded by singles quotes on the outside.

Comment: It would be simpler to just set `cilist` to some value in the first script, and let the second script echo it. Then explain why what is being echoed is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell treats the quote characters as special characters. For double quote (`"`), it treats the enclosed data as a single argument to the command. This would be useful if the input had a space (or other shell separator token) within it. However, when the argument is provided to the command, the quote is removed.

You can try using backslash (`\`) to escape the double quote. But, you may still want to enclose everything with a double quote incase `$cilist` has input that requires quoting.

```
script.sh -cis "\"$cilist\""
```

Comment: When using the suggested way the variable is pasted with an extra ' in it:
-cis '"806a21565febe9a4c146272402e267c9,81c130e48144b9b8d8ad5ebef639d67c"'

Comment: There is no single quote in my answer.

Comment: Hi @jhx When i execute my first script to retrieve the values i want to store in the variable cilist and then use the valuest in the second script it fails because apparentely there are single quotes surrounding the values in the variable cilist

So what i get is this when i execute the second script:

script2.sh - cis "\"$cilist\""

set -x output:
- cis '"806a21565febe9a4c146272402e267c9,81c130e48144b9b8d8ad5ebef639d67c"'

so the variable gets enclosed with single quotes in the beginning and end.

Comment: That runs counter to your question, which said that `echo $cilist` did not have any quotes in it.

Comment: Here is an experiment: `x="$(echo '""')"` followed by `echo $x`

Comment: @jhx: using your earlier provided info to use "\"$cilist\"" i have adjusted my original post to what output i get.